# How to change dataframe on button click

Tags: python, plotly

I am using code on this page: [Plotly: How to filter a pandas dataframe using a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406167/plotly-how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-a-dropdown-menu)

I have a global dataframe df that has all the timestamps and frequencies. Now I have created separate dataframes and created a list out of them. I need to switch to different dataframe in array if the button is clicked
This is how I have created a new dataframe

```
dates = freq.date.unique()
N = -7 #Number of last days
index = 0
updatemenu = []
buttons = []
bar = []
for date in sorted(dates)[N: len(dates)]:
    bar.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["timestamp", "freq"]))
    bar[index]["timestamp"] = pd.date_range(str(date)+" 00:00:00+00:00", str(date)+" 23:59:00+00:00", freq="3min")
    bar[index]["freq"] = 0
    freq_temp = freq.loc[freq.date == pd.to_datetime(date)]

    for i in freq_temp.timestamp:
        for j in bar[index].timestamp:

            delta = math.ceil(abs(i-j).seconds/60)

            if(delta <= 3):

                v = bar[index].loc[pd.to_datetime(bar[index].timestamp) == pd.to_datetime(j) ,"freq"]
                v = freq.loc[pd.to_datetime(freq.timestamp) == pd.to_datetime(i) ,"freq"].to_string(index=False)
                bar[index].loc[pd.to_datetime(bar[index].timestamp) == pd.to_datetime(j) ,"freq"] = v
                break
                
    index = index + 1
```

And this is how I am plotting

```
fig = go.Figure()

# set up ONE trace
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=bar[0].timestamp,
                         y=bar[0].freq,
                         visible=True)
             )

updatemenu = []
buttons = []

# button with one option for each dataframe
for index in range(0,len(bar)):
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label= str(dates[index]),
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[bar[index].timestamp],
                               'x':[bar[index].freq],
                               'type':'bar'}, [0]],
                        )
                  )

# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu = []
your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

After second date it doesn't show correct graphs. And it shows first graph once before it shows the graph with the button. Here is what dataframe looks like
[bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Fc4.png)

This is a bar dataframe at specific index.