# Trying to Create Plotly Dropdown Control Based on Unique Items in a Dataframe Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have this simple dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'123'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':2000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'456'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':10000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':2000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-05-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'789'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Based on unique IDs in the ID column, I am trying to crate a dropdown control.

```
# uniques = df['ID'].unique()
# for i in uniques:
#    print(i)
```

I'm testing this code, and it looks pretty close, but it's not actually generating a chart for me.

```
uniques = df['ID'].unique()

# plotly
fig = go.Figure()

# set up ONE trace
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df[df.columns[0]],
                         visible=True)
             )

updatemenu = []
buttons = []

# button with one option for each dataframe
for i in uniques:
    #print(i)
    #df_single = df[df['ID']==i]
    #data=df_single
    #print(data)
    
     buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                         label=i,
                         visible=True,
                         args=[{'y':[df['ID']==i],
                                'x':[df.index],
                                'type':'scatter'}]
                         )
                   )

    
# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu = []

your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

I am leveraging two resources for this.

[Plotly: How to filter a pandas dataframe using a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406167/plotly-how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-a-dropdown-menu)

https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick.

```
df_test = df.pivot(index='Month', columns='ID', values='Expense')

# plotly
fig = go.Figure()

# set up ONE trace
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_test.index,
                         y=df_test[df_test.columns[0]],
                         visible=True)
             )

updatemenu = []
buttons = []

# button with one option for each dataframe
for i in df_test.columns:
    print(i)
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=i,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df_test[i]],
                               'x':[df_test.index],
                               'type':'scatter'}, [0]],
                        )
                  )
    
# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu = []
your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True


# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

[image]